# listview jquery mobile php

Tags: php, jquery, cordova, listview

I have created following query, which shows results from a mysql database and fetched in the phonegap app. I want to display the results in the usual jquery mobile listview typ. however, i'm getting a normal html list displayed in the app.

Here is the first part of my jquery form in my app.

```
    <!-- Krankenkasse -->
    <div data-role="page" id="p4">
        <div data-role="header" data-position="fixed">

            <a href="#p2" data-icon="arrow-l" data-transition="slide" data-direction="reverse">zurück</a>
            <center>
                <img class="logo" src="img/logo2.png">
            </center>
            <a  href="#p5"  data-icon="arrow-r" value="Submit" id="myButton" data-transition="slide">weiter</a> 
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {

        $("#myButton").click(function(){
            $("#krankenkasse").submit();
        });
        $("#krankenkasse").submit(function(event){
             event.preventDefault();
            $("#ajax-loader").css("display","block");
            $("#output").html("Loading Result...");
            $.ajax({
                url: 'http://app.lovanet.ch/app/db_eingabe.php',
                data: $(this).serialize(),
                method: 'POST',
                success: function(data, status){
                    $("#ajax-loader").css("display","none");
                    $("#output").html(data);
                },
                error: function(){
                    output.text('Keine Prämien gefunden.');
                }
            });
        });
    });
</script>
        </div>
        <div data-role="content">
            <div data-role="fieldcontain">
                <h1>
            Krankenkasse
                </h1>
                <form id="krankenkasse" action="#5"  method="POST">
 <div data-role="fieldcontain">                  
                     <fieldset data-role="controlgroup">
                    <legend><b>Ich bin...</b>
                    </legend>
                    <input type="radio" name="altersklasse" id="alter1" value="1" checked="checked" />
                    <label for="alter1">18 Jahre alt oder jünger</label>

                    <input type="radio" name="altersklasse" id="alter2" value="2" />
                    <label for="alter2">zwischen 19 und 25 Jahre alt</label>

                    <input type="radio" name="altersklasse" id="alter3" value="3" />
                    <label for="alter3">26 Jahre alt oder älter</label>
                </fieldset>
                </div>
                <br>
```

and here is the sql query. I tried to insert data-role="listview" in the , but this does not work. How I can display the results in listview type

```
      <?php

        include "db_connect.inc.php";

    $sql = "SELECT * FROM praemien, plz";
    $sql .= " WHERE franchise = ". $_POST["franchise"] ." ";
    $sql .= " AND plz.ort_id = praemien.ort_id AND plz.plz = '" . $_POST["plz"] . "' ";
    $sql .= " AND plz.ort_id = praemien.ort_id AND plz.gemeinde LIKE '" . $_POST["gemeinde"] . "' ";
    $sql .= "AND altersklasse = '" . $_POST["altersklasse"] . "' AND ";

    switch($_POST["unfall"])
    { case 1:
        $sql .="unfalleinschluss like 'OHN-UNF'";
        break;
     case 2:
        $sql .="unfalleinschluss like 'MIT-UNF'";
    } 

$tbs = array();

foreach( array( 'tb1', 'tb2', 'tb3', 'tb4' ) as $tb_key )
{
    if ( empty( $_POST[$tb_key] ) ) continue;

    $tbs[] = "`tarif-typ` LIKE '" . $_POST[$tb_key] . "'";
}
if ( !empty( $tbs ) )
{
    $sql .= ' AND ( ' . implode( ' OR ', $tbs ) . ' )';
}

    $sql .= " order by praemie";



    $res = mysqli_query($con, $sql);
    $num = mysqli_num_rows($res);
    if ($num==0) echo "Keine Datensätze gefunden";
    echo '<ul data-role="listview" data-inset="true">';
    while ($dsatz = mysqli_fetch_assoc($res))
    echo '<li>'
        .$dsatz["versicherungsnamen"] . ", "
        .$dsatz["kanton"] . ", "
        .$dsatz["franchise"] . ", "
        .$dsatz["tarif-typ"] . ", "
        .$dsatz["region_id"] . ", "
        .$dsatz["unfalleinschluss"] . ", "
        .$dsatz["altersklasse"] . ", "
        .$dsatz["praemie"] . ", "
        .$dsatz["gemeinde"] . "</li>"; 

        mysqli_close($con);
    echo '</ul>';   
        ?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If refreshing the listview is still not ok, use this;

`$('#id').trigger("create");`

#### JQ

```
$("#krankenkasse").submit(function(event){
    event.preventDefault();
    $("#ajax-loader").css("display","block");
    $("#output").html("Loading Result...");
    $.ajax({
        url: 'http://app.lovanet.ch/app/db_eingabe.php',
        data: $(this).serialize(),
        method: 'POST',
        success: function(data, status){
            $("#ajax-loader").css("display","none");
            $("#output").html(data);
            // create mobile style listview
            $("#output").trigger("create");
        },
        error: function(){
            output.text('Keine Prämien gefunden.');
        }
    });
})
```

Comment: This seems to work partially, becase a part of the information are cut. 1 line per data is shown only.

Answer (score 0):

You need to run the `refresh` method on the new HTML content.

Docs: http://demos.jquerymobile.com/1.2.1/docs/lists/lists-methods.html

```
    $("#krankenkasse").submit(function(event){
         event.preventDefault();
        $("#ajax-loader").css("display","block");
        $("#output").html("Loading Result...");
        $.ajax({
            url: 'http://app.lovanet.ch/app/db_eingabe.php',
            data: $(this).serialize(),
            method: 'POST',
            success: function(data, status){
                $("#ajax-loader").css("display","none");
                $("#output").html(data);
                // Now refresh here
                $("#output").listview('refresh');
            },
            error: function(){
                output.text('Keine Prämien gefunden.');
            }
        });
    })
```

Comment: Hi Rob, thanks for your reply. However, it does not work. the results are displayed in the html manner again.

Comment: Can you setup a jsfiddle.net with just your basic page HTML and then also please put the output of the `submit` in a commented section of the HTML so we can check what's going on.

Comment: ok I will do. However, I can do it not before this evening,  because I'm leaving now the office.

Comment: Hi there, sorry for the delay, but I was off the last days. I could resolve it. I entered in the php file `echo <ul data-role="listview" data-inset="true">';` and in the script I put `            // create mobile style listview
            $("#output").trigger("create");
`